# Where should we write validation code for a form in cfwheels?

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have just started learning cfwheels. I was working on the sample "Social Networking Site" example present in the site(http://cfwheels.org/screencasts/series/1).
I have a doubt. We have register.cfm and login.cfm two views present. Both the veiws are using the user object
created from Person.cfc(modal).

All the validations that are required in the registration form , we have written inside Person.cfc `init()` method. Now on the login.cfm
we have two fields named `Email and password` and I want to `validate` the email to be in `correct format` in server side before checking
for valid Email/Password combination.

Now where should I write this validation code for login.cfm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server side validation should be done on the action inside the Controller.
For example if you are submitting the form to `doLogin` action of the `Authentication` controller/component, the validation code should go inside the `doLogin()` function of the same controller.

Comment: But in the Example for registration form validation, the validation code was inside the Person.cfc modal not inside the `Main` controllers `register` action. thats why I am confused validation should be inside model or controller?

Comment: Anything written in Model cfc is meant for database. If you want CFWheels to validate data while performing database operations then the validation code should go in Model cfc. But if you want server side validation then it's always the Controller where you write the validation.